# CRON Expression

Tags: cron, crontrigger

Hi Anyone have idea on the CRON EXpression which Fires every 30 minutes starting at 7:00 AM and ending at 7:00 PM, AND fire every 1 hour starting at 7:00 PM and ending at 6:00 AM in the next day, every day

Comment: This would be better asked on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with 2 tasks of cron:

```
30 7-19 * * * 
60 19-6 * * *
```