# Cron Expression With Complex Timing

Tags: java, cron, annotations, guice, quartz

I have a java application using quartz that needs to run a job at different intervals over the course of the day. It should run every 30 minutes between 8AM and 4PM, skip 4PM to 6PM, and then run every other hour between 6PM and 8AM. I can create a cron expression for any one of those timings but I can't figure out how to combine them into a single expression.

All of the solutions I have found so far ([CRON Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917397/cron-expression)
and
[Cron expression with start and end time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832131/cron-expression-with-start-and-end-time))
seem to suggest using multiple cron expressions. I'm using quartz (or in my case guartz for guice compatibility) annotations and I'm not sure how to do that.

Is there some way to define the scheduling for my job with a single cron expression? If not, what are my alternatives using quartz?

Comment: All the solutions that you found are correct. You should use multiple cron expressions. What you need cannot be expressed with single cron expression.

Comment: You can use comma separated lists ` 0 0 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,19,20 ? * * *` in the hour or you have to just use two triggers.   I've used both of these methods based on what the CRON string looks like or if it makes sense to separate them.

Comment: @ Mirek Pluta, @ kendavidson Ok, so how do I actually add multiple triggers or cron expressions to a single job using quartz in java?

Comment: Sorry, not sure if you've resolved this.  But it all depends on how you're configuring quartz? Code or XML?